# Why are my contracts created from a Factory appearing in etherscan as normal accounts and not contract accounts?

Tags: contract-deployment, etherscan

I have a factory on rinkby testnet that creates other contracts.

These other contracts are shown as normal human accounts, and not contract accounts.

It appears that the code for the factory and the contracts it makes is all stored at the factory address. Is this why it appears this way on etherscan?

Ultimately, what I want to know is are these factory created contracts really contract accounts? or are they normal accounts?

Comment: Do you have an example address or the code of your factory? Sometimes Etherscan is just slow to update their database.

Comment: From my experience this sometimes happens but fixes itself over time. Did this problem occur directly after you created the contract or is it a long-term issue?